# After downgrade gcc Nvidia driver doesen't work,fallback to default gcc doesn't work

Tags: gcc

As I downgrade the gcc to 4.4 I changed the symlinks to the 4.4 Version. This doesen't work and now my System (kubuntu 20.04 64bit) doesen't boot. As I learned now the Nvidia driver need the gcc compiler to work. Now I would like to get back to the default gcc but it doesen't work. What did I done yet

```
$ sudo apt remove build-essential
$ sudo apt purge gcc
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

Then `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get install -f`

After that I tried to install the `build essential` package, but this ended with errors. The gcc and g++ package is not configured and so the dependencies of build essential doesn't exist

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Die folgenden zusätzlichen Pakete werden installiert:
g++ g++-9 gcc libstdc++-9-dev
Vorgeschlagene Pakete:
g++-multilib g++-9-multilib gcc-9-doc gcc-multilib autoconf automake libtool flex bison gcc-doc libstdc++-9-doc
Die folgenden NEUEN Pakete werden installiert:
build-essential g++ g++-9 gcc libstdc++-9-dev
0 aktualisiert, 5 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 10,1 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 46,8 MB Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket gcc wird gewählt.
(Lese Datenbank ... 262920 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../gcc_4%3a9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket libstdc++-9-dev:amd64 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../libstdc++-9-dev_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von libstdc++-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket g++-9 wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../g++-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von g++-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket g++ wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../g++_4%3a9.3.0-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von g++ (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) ...
Vormals nicht ausgewähltes Paket build-essential wird gewählt.
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../build-essential_12.8ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Entpacken von build-essential (12.8ubuntu1.1) ...
libstdc++-9-dev:amd64 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) wird eingerichtet ...
gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) wird eingerichtet ...
update-alternatives: Fehler: Alternativen-Pfad /usr/bin/gcc existiert nicht
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes gcc (--configure):
»installiertes gcc-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 2 zurück
g++-9 (9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) wird eingerichtet ...
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von g++:
g++ hängt ab von gcc (= 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2); aber:
Paket gcc ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes g++ (--configure):
Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da die Fehlermeldung darauf hindeutet, dass dies lediglich ein Folgefehler eines vorherigen Problems ist.
Es wurde kein Apport-Bericht verfasst, da die Fehlermeldung darauf hindeut
et, dass dies lediglich ein Folgefehler eines vorherigen Problems ist.
dpkg: Abhängigkeitsprobleme verhindern Konfiguration von build-essential:
build-essential hängt ab von gcc (>= 4:9.2); aber:
Paket gcc ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
build-essential hängt ab von g++ (>= 4:9.2); aber:
Paket g++ ist noch nicht konfiguriert.
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes build-essential (--configure):
Abhängigkeitsprobleme - verbleibt unkonfiguriert
Trigger für man-db (2.9.1-1) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
gcc
g++
build-essential
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

`ls -l /usr/bin` shows me

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Mär 20  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-g++ -> g++-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1158288 Aug  8  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Mär 20  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> gcc-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1154192 Aug  8  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Mär 20  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35464 Aug  8  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Mär 20  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35464 Aug  8  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          12 Mär 20  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35464 Aug  8  2020  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9
```

whereby `find . -xtype l` shows me following broken links

```
./gcc-nm
./gcc-ar
./x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
./x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm
./gcc-ranlib
./x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar
./clhsdb
./x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib
./gcc
./hsdb
```

The output of `apt-cache policy gcc` is

```
gcc:
  Installiert:           4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Installationskandidat: 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

A `sudo dpkg --configure gcc` ends also with an error (errorcode 2)

```
gcc (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2) wird eingerichtet ...
update-alternatives: Fehler: Alternativen-Pfad /usr/bin/gcc existiert nicht
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes gcc (--configure):
 »installiertes gcc-Skript des Paketes post-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 2 zurück
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 gcc
```

My question is how can I fix the broken links to install finally the default gcc.Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What do the more interesting symlinks /usr/bin/gcc, /usr/bin/gcc-9, ...etc. link to?  Those are probably the ones used when you try to build anything.

Comment: I can't find symlinks  /usr/bin/gcc, /usr/bin/gcc-9, ...etc.

Comment: That's your problem then.  Create them linking to the system supplied defaults (gcc-9, g++-9, etc.) sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-9 /usr/bin/gcc   etc.

Comment: Sorry for the next question, but how can I find out whats are the system supplied defaults?

Comment: the package g++ (, gcc,) ... is the metapackage which installs the default version.  Use the command (in a terminal) apt-cache depends g++  Its output contains the g++# where # is the  package for the default version.  There are generally two older versions available if needed, as separate installs.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem last weekend. Here are the defines of my missing/broken symlinks:

```
sudo ln -s gcc-9 gcc
sudo ln -s gcc-9 gcc
sudo ln -s gcc-ar-9 gcc-ar
sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9 gcc-ar-9
sudo ln -s gcc-nm-9 gcc-nm
sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9 gcc-nm-9
sudo ln -s gcc-ranlib-9 gcc-ranlib
sudo ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9 gcc-ranlib-9
sudo ln -s gcc-9 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc
```

Now a `$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep gcc` outputs

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         428 Mai  7  2006 c89-gcc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         454 Apr 11  2011 c99-gcc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Mär 19 21:47 gcc -> gcc-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          22 Mär 19 21:49 gcc-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Mär 19 21:50 gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          25 Mär 19 21:51 gcc-ar-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Mär 20  2020 gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          25 Mär 19 21:53 gcc-nm-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          12 Mär 20  2020 gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          29 Mär 19 21:56 gcc-ranlib-9 -> x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           5 Mär 20  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -> gcc-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1154192 Aug  8  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Mär 20  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar -> gcc-ar-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35464 Aug  8  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ar-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           8 Mär 20  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm -> gcc-nm-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35464 Aug  8  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-nm-9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          12 Mär 20  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib -> gcc-ranlib-9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       35464 Aug  8  2020 x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib-9
```

Thanks a lot for the hints und support.